# Have you ever received the highest performance rating but not gotten a raise?

Tags: salary, performance-reviews

This happened to me twice in the recent past, My manager was incredulous that his manager overrode his salary recommendation. The first time I went to HR and asked about it, I told them "if this is company policy for all who were in my same situation (theres a salary matrix for every position, and I was in a pay range where they would give raises as per their written policy) Im fine with it".  "Is this the policy?" The HR rep said they did not know.  This seemed impossible but thats the all I could do.
The second time, they said we will check into it.  Then, in spite of the fact that my review was officially approved by my manager's manager, they said that that rating was not allowed, and my review had to be downgraded and reapproved.  No raise again, and a downgraded rating.  Does this go on in other companies?

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question here.  More of a  rant.

Comment: I hope this isn't a common practice in the workforce and you get some resolution to this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately polling questions are off topic.  I'd suggest trying chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler

Comment: I see how it can be viewed and as polling or a rant, yet often Ive simply wondered what the rest of the working world is like, these are things Im reluctant to share in my workplace, and Ive simply sucked it up, maybe Im a dope for allowing this sort of treatment or its what everyone deals with.

Comment: Not a good situation.  Your manager should not have shared salary or rating with you until it was final.

Comment: I was a low level manager for a large IT outsourcing company and they pulled this crap CONSTANTLY.  I got to see behind the scenes what was really going on.  If I were you I would be looking for another job.  If you'd like to know more about my experience hit me up and I'll be happy to chat.

Comment: Not sure why everyone thinks this isn't a question, but sometimes this place can get bonkers with people putting questions on hold or claiming duplicates all over the place. I don't know how common this is...but it seems incredibly likely. I've definitely seen it. Prior very political / drama-filled places. The level of review is separated out from the raise. There is supposed to be some connection, but managers have a lot of leeway. Your boss's boss doesn't like you. That's kind of the root of your problem here. I'd probably leave if they downgraded your review, you aren't going to recover.

Comment: Yes that has happened at other companies. Did you get what you were looking for?

Comment: I worked for several companies who did performance reviews at calendar yearend, but raises at fiscal yearend. So many people got great reviews with no raise.

Answer (score 2):

> Have you ever received the highest performance rating but not gotten a
>   raise?

Yes, but the circumstances don't match yours. In my case, the company was in a tight financial situation, and nobody got raises that year. That fact was communicated publicly to everyone.

> Does this go on in other companies?

Perhaps. My guess is that your manager and your manager's boss didn't agree on your review and/or raise.

That happens.

Good companies have processes in place where the details are resolved and disagreements ironed out *before* any discussion with the employee occurs. That 
way, you can avoid the situation you find yourself in.

It could be just a case of a poorly executed process. Or it could be something else. And it doesn't really matter if this happens at other companies or not. What matters is what happened at your company and what you can do about it.

If you are friendly and close enough to your manager, a quiet, private conversation with him could enlighten you as to what actually happened.

You might find that there's something you personally need to do in the future to get a raise. Or you might find that something else is happening in the company or department.

Comment: The simple answer HR could have said is "no one is getting a raise" I practically handed them that exit, but they dithered and did not take it.  ergo, I was treated differently than others. The only lever I have is my performance, and as far as the rating system is concerned - its stellar.  It seems theres probably some unwritten things Im not getting.